# xmpp: ios: get user's current status after unblocking

Tags: ios, xmpp, block

I am developing an iOS chat application using XMPP. My problem is that, I have user A and B, User A blocks User B, while User B is available. Next User B goes busy and User A unblocks User B, User A sees User B as available rather than busy. How can I get user's current status after unblocking? I've read through XMPP documentation but it din't help.

A quick response is very appreciable